# How to create a csv file of a form / table in ionic mobile app?

Tags: csv, ionic-framework

I am not able to find how I can create a `csv` or `xls` file of a table where data is inserted by users. I want a button that saves data as `csv/xls` file-format in ionic apps.

I have one form with a save button that saves data of the form in SQLite. I can also retrieve data in a table. Now, I want this table data to be saved in my ionic app. I used `ng-csv`, `ng-sanitizer` to handle this, this worked just fine in browser but the button does not fire in the application.

How can I handle that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @abarisone thank you.
I have one form with a save button that saves data of the form in sqlite. I can also be able to retrieve data in a table. Now, i want this table data to be saved in my ionic app. I used ng-csv, ng-sanitizer to handle this, this worked just fine in browser but button does not fire in app.

Comment: Your comment could be an edit to your question, so this is what I have just done

Answer (score 2):

First of all, 
Convert the data from json object to CSV.

```
 function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                if (line != '') line += ','

                line += array[i][index];
            }

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Then just write the csv values as writeFile to externalRootDirectory.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


      $scope.exportCSV = function (data){
      console.log(data);
      var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log(jsonObject);
      var finalCSV = ConvertToCSV(jsonObject);
      console.log(finalCSV);

          //alert('cordova.file.dataDirectory: ' + cordova); //I get [object Object]
         //  alert('cordova.file.dataDirectory: ' + cordova.file.dataDirectory); // I get file is undefined
           $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'data.csv', finalCSV, true).then(function(result){
            alert('Success! Export created!');
          }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
          })

         }

       });
```

And in the emulator or android device rootDirectory, which will be get by 
Console.log(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory) or alert(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory)

Go to that directories and you will get your csv file, like this you can easily export the file with any kind of format.

Comment: I have downloaded ur complete solution last night @motiur.ion. It neither works in browser nor in emulator/mobile........ It gets installed but does not load up in mobile/emulator

Comment: Why you told me about my complete solution ? It may broken the code but the main code snipped I paste here so that you can try by yourself and another thing is that when you ask a question then you have to give your code also what you already have done... @monir